# Help samsung home pin

Tags: screen, sim-unlocking, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I have a *Samsung Galaxy S3 mini*. Sometimes when I go to enter my PIN, if I touch anywhere on the screen i.e. on my screen saver, any of the numbers, or go, it just inputs "0" in the entry box. How can I stop this? All I've got to do is turn the screen off and back on and it refreshes.